# 0F1h opcode-prefix on i80286

Tags: 80286, undocumented-opcodes

On Intel iAPX **80286**, as I recall from experience, the undocumented – officially unassigned – opcode position `0F1h` was actually decoded as an instruction prefix, thus counting for maximum allowed instruction length (ten bytes), but otherwise not modifying the prefixed instruction: a "no operation" prefix of sorts. Now, what I have always wondered and could not ascertain, lacking appropriate lab equipment (logic analyzer or a mere oscilloscope): was `0F1h` perhaps an alias for the lock prefix (`0F0h`), or was it just ignored by the CPU (apart from counting for instruction length)?

Note: we know that position `0F1h` of the opcode matrix was later reused for a one-byte `int 1` opcode (not a prefix) starting with the **i80386**, that also was not documented until much later. This later conflicting assignment of the opcode position is *not* part of the question here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While it is officially documented as "a prefix which performs no function", [a thread on the vcfed.org forums](http://www.vcfed.org/forum/showthread.php?70386-I-found-the-SAVEALL-opcode&p=576206#post576206) has discovered it is an ICE-mode prefix that forces the instruction's memory access to be performed using the normal bus pins instead of the extra pins normally used by the bond-out version of the 286.

Comment: Thank you for that, @Philip ! Truly amazing find!... $Deity$ knows how much time I spent fiddling with loadall and the 0F.04, varying conditions, with controlled shutdowns and NMIs, back in ~1990 ... I always suspected 0F.04 would be a "store all" to "alternate" memory (which I could not test) ! At the same time I was also well aware of F1 being a (practically) "no op" prefix, yet trying to prefix 0F.04 by F1 never occurred to me ! Wow !

Comment: By a slight extension one would want to assert the same question - about prefix F1 - on the 8086/88 (original or CMOS versions), and the 186 as well. On those older CPUs where opcode decoding reportedly was done more in "logic" than thru micro (nano?)-programming, it is conceivable that F1==F0, if you pardon the language...

Answer (score 12):

According to [an Intel document describing opcodes which don’t result in exception 6](https://www.pcjs.org/pubs/pc/reference/intel/80286/exceptions/),

> The 0F1H opcode is a prefix which performs no function. It counts like any other prefix towards the maximum instruction length. No restrictions apply to its execution.

The same document mentions explicitly when opcodes are aliases for others. I interpret the above as meaning that 0xF1 is *not* an alias for 0xF0. If it was, I would have hoped the locking behaviour would be mentioned.

However [this 2010 post in `comp.lang.asm.x86`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.asm.x86/1xYGbLfanco) does mention that 0xF1 *is* an alias for 0xF0, and that the only way to determine this is by testing it, since the Intel documentation is unreliable.

I don’t have a 286 handy to test this behaviour though. To test this on a real 80286, you’d need either a logic analyser (as you mention), or a protected-mode test program — since `LOCK` is a privileged prefix, if 0xF1 is an alias for it, it should generate a general protection fault if it’s used without the appropriate privilege. (On a 386 or later CPU, the test would be easier, since `LOCK` with an inappropriate instruction or operand generates an invalid opcode exception, but 0xF1 is different there.)

Comment: How come `LOCK` is privileged? Many modern atomic operations in user space rely on this prefix. Did it behave different on a 286?

Comment: @Ruslan as I understand the 286 manual, the 286 designers considered that it caused I/O (in the shape of the `LOCK#` signal), so if IOPL < CPL the operation causes an exception. The I/O permission model changed with the 386. However I have conflicting docs around `LOCK` on 286s, so really its behaviour should be tested on a real 286...

Comment: Would a test on an AMD 286 be of any use?

Comment: @Ruslan yes, they were licensed clones, and should behave identically to Intel CPUs. The things I’d like to test, beyond the 0xF0/0xF1 equivalence, are: is `LOCK` allowed with any instruction, or does it produce an invalid opcode exception with anything other than `INS`, `MOVS`, `OUTS` and `XCHG`? Does the behaviour change in protected mode? And obviously the IOPL behaviour above ;-).

Comment: I might try to test sometime on this weekend.

Comment: (While I’m at it, I’d also like to check whether the 286 restarts repeating instructions properly when `REP` isn’t the last prefix; that’s a known 8086 bug but it’s unclear whether it’s fixed on the 286.)

Comment: @Ruslan that would be fantastic! Incidentally, if `LOCK` does produce an invalid opcode exception when used with non-lockable instructions, it’s much easier to test the 0xF1 equivalence ;-).

Comment: @Stephen : There was no concept of lockable/not lockable instruction on the 286, LOCK could prefix *any* instruction w/o producing an exception 06, and was supposed to assert the #lock signal to the memory controller.

Comment: @NimbUs yes, that’s what I thought, as described in the Intel manuals; but I’ve got programming manuals which say it’s only allowed with the instructions above, which is why I’m curious about the real behaviour on a 286. (I never had to look into this when I worked on 286s...)

Comment: @Stephen Kitt : I /did/ test the previously mentioned behaviour on real 286s (several pieces, including authorized clones). The only exception LOCK could cause (though indirectly) was by contributing to exceeding maximum instruction length (or trespassing CS limit) - and then that would be GPF, not UNDefined instruction.

Comment: @NimbUs excellent, thanks for the confirmation! (I didn’t mean to imply you hadn’t tested the behaviour, I was only explaining why I was interested in such tests.) Did you ever test the protected mode behaviour described in my answer?

Comment: I have tried this now, see my answer. I've also checked that `lock mov ax, ax` (which is not lockable on modern CPUs) doesn't lead to any exception in ring 0 on 286, although it generates #UD in Bochs and on Pentium 4.

Answer (score 6):

I've done an experiment to confirm what Stephen Kitt says in his answer. I've tried some instructions on my AMD 286 system, using the boot sector-based playground given at the bottom of this answer (compilable with FASM).

Namely, when I have `lock` uncommented and `db 0xf1` commented out (see the code after the `enterRing3` label), my 286 system prints `#BP #GP` (#BP for `int3` and #GP for `LOCK ADD`), which confirms that the `LOCK` prefix is privileged on 80286. If I run the code with `lock` commented out and `db 0xf1` uncommented, I get the same result as when both prefixes are commented out, i.e. `#BP #DE` (#BP for `int3` and #DE for `DIV`), which confirms that the `F1` prefix is simply ignored instead of being equivalent to `LOCK`, and also that it doesn't result in #UD (which is why I use division by zero instead of `UD2` at the end).

The boot sector of the playground:

```
 BOOT_ADDR = 0x7c00
 org BOOT_ADDR
 use16

 CODE_SELECTOR_RING0     = code_descr_ring0 - gdt
 CODE_SELECTOR_RING3     = (code_descr_ring3 - gdt) or 3
 DATA_SELECTOR_RING0     = data_descr_ring0 - gdt
 DATA_SELECTOR_RING3     = (data_descr_ring3 - gdt) or 3
 VRAM_SELECTOR           = vram_descr - gdt
 TSS_SELECTOR            = tss - gdt

 macro GDT_ENTRY_286 base_,limit_,present_,ring_,system_,codeseg_,conforming_,writable_,accessed_
 {
     dw       limit_
     dw       base_ and 0xffff
     db       base_ shr 16
     db       (present_ shl 7) or (ring_ shl 5) or (system_ shl 4) or (codeseg_ shl 3) or (conforming_ shl 2) or (writable_ shl 1) or accessed_
     dw       0     ; reserved on 286
 }
 PRESENT_SEG=1
 ABSENT_SEG=0
 SYSTEM_SEG=0
 NONSYSTEM_SEG=1
 DATA_SEG=0
 CODE_SEG=1
 CONFORMING_SEG=1
 EXT_DOWNWARDS_SEG=CONFORMING_SEG ; same bit, but for data segments
 NONCONFORMING_SEG=0
 EXT_UPWARDS_SEG=NONCONFORMING_SEG ; same bit, but for data segments
 WRITABLE_SEG=1
 READABLE_SEG=WRITABLE_SEG ; same bit, but for code segments
 NONWRITABLE_SEG=0
 ACCESSED_SEG=1
 NOT_ACCESSED_SEG=0

    jmp      0x0000:start ; make sure we know distribution of linear address bits between CS and IP
start:
    ; print "OK" on the screen to see that we've actually started
    push     0xb800
    pop      es
    xor      di,di
    mov      ax, 0x0700+'O'
    stosw
    mov      ax, 0x0700+'K'
    stosw
    ; clear the rest of the screen to have a clear view of the exceptions we'll generate
    mov      cx, 80*25*2-2
    mov      ax, 0x0700+' '
    rep stosw

    lgdt     [cs:gdtr]
    cli
    mov      cx, DATA_SELECTOR_RING0
    smsw     ax
    or       al, 1
    lmsw     ax
    jmp      CODE_SELECTOR_RING0:enterPM
enterPM:
    mov      ds, cx
    mov      ss, cx
    mov      sp, 0xfffe
    lidt     [idtr]

    ; fill ring0 stack in the TSS and load TR - so that we could handle ring3-originating exceptions
    mov      word [2], sp   ; ring0 SP
    mov      word [4], cx   ; ring0 ss
    mov      dx, TSS_SELECTOR
    ltr      dx

    mov      ax, sp
    push     DATA_SELECTOR_RING3
    push     ax
    pushf
    push     CODE_SELECTOR_RING3
    push     enterRing3
    iret
enterRing3:
    push     ss
    pop      ds
    int3     ; check that at least interrupts and returns from them work
    db       0xf1 ; the prefix we wanted to check for equivalence to LOCK
;    lock          ; LOCK itself
    add word [0], 0
    xor      ax, ax      ; make sure we don't pass
    div      ax          ; through to execute data
gdt:
    dq       0
data_descr_ring0:
    GDT_ENTRY_286 0x00000,0xffff,PRESENT_SEG,0,NONSYSTEM_SEG,DATA_SEG,EXT_UPWARDS_SEG,WRITABLE_SEG,ACCESSED_SEG
data_descr_ring3:
    GDT_ENTRY_286 0x10000,0xffff,PRESENT_SEG,3,NONSYSTEM_SEG,DATA_SEG,EXT_UPWARDS_SEG,WRITABLE_SEG,ACCESSED_SEG
vram_descr:
    GDT_ENTRY_286 0xb8000,0xffff,PRESENT_SEG,0,NONSYSTEM_SEG,DATA_SEG,EXT_UPWARDS_SEG,WRITABLE_SEG,ACCESSED_SEG
code_descr_ring0:
    GDT_ENTRY_286 0x00000,0xffff,PRESENT_SEG,0,NONSYSTEM_SEG,CODE_SEG,NONCONFORMING_SEG,READABLE_SEG,ACCESSED_SEG
code_descr_ring3:
    GDT_ENTRY_286 0x00000,0xffff,PRESENT_SEG,3,NONSYSTEM_SEG,CODE_SEG,NONCONFORMING_SEG,READABLE_SEG,ACCESSED_SEG
tss:
    GDT_ENTRY_286 0x00000,0x002c,PRESENT_SEG,3,SYSTEM_SEG,0,0,0,1 ; 16-bit available TSS (in place of real-mode IVT)

gdtr:
    dw       gdtr-gdt-1
 gdtBase:
    dd       gdt

idt:
 rept 14 COUNTER
 {
    dw       intHandler#COUNTER
    dw       CODE_SELECTOR_RING0
    db       0
    db       11100111b    ; present, ring3, system, 16-bit trap gate
    dw       0            ; reserved on 286
 }
idtr:
    dw       idtr-idt-1
 idtBase:
    dd       idt

INT_NAME_SIZE=3
 rept 14 COUNTER
 {
intHandler#COUNTER:
    mov      si, intNames+(COUNTER-1)*INT_NAME_SIZE
    mov      bx, COUNTER-1
    jmp      handleInt
 }
handleInt:
    pusha
    push     ds
    mov      cx, VRAM_SELECTOR
    mov      es, cx
    push     ss
    pop      ds
    mov      di, [offsetInVRAM]
    mov      cx, INT_NAME_SIZE
    mov      al, 7
 printLoop:
    movsb     ; character
    stosb     ; attribute
    loop     printLoop
    inc      di
    inc      di
    mov      [offsetInVRAM], di
    cmp      bx, 3 ; test that our interrupts work as expected, return after INT3
    jne      $
    pop      ds
    popa
    iret
intNames:
    db "#DE#DBNMI#BP#OF#BR#UD#NM#DFCSO#TS#NP#SS#GP"
offsetInVRAM:
    dw       0

finish:
    db       (0x7dfe-finish) dup(0)
    dw       0xaa55
```

Comment: Good debugging job ! ... As for me, can only lament that both my 286 & 386 boards are out of order, permanently ;=)

Comment: Nice, so that confirms what the Intel docs say!